# How to test if Flow & combine switched data correctly , test execution finishes before flow has been updated

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have a Flow<PagingData> that depends on two different values to filter between premium and regular users, but also with a "query" string to filter by names

```
class DataViewModel : ViewModel() {

  val query = MutableStateFlow("")
  val filter = MutableStateFlow("ALL")

 val allListItemsLiveData: Flow<PagingData<DataModel>> = combine(query, filter) { query, filter ->
        Pair(query, filter)
    }.flatMapLatest {
        val query = it.first
        val filter = it.second
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 40,
                prefetchDistance = 60,
                initialLoadSize = 100,
                enablePlaceholders = true
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = {
                when (filter) {
                    PREMIUM -> database.getPremiumWithQuery(query)
                    ALL -> database.getAllWithQuery(query)
                }
            },
            remoteMediator = null
        ).flow
         .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

I want to test if paging data filters correctly the query term, but the execution of test finishes before paging data has been updated, so how can i monitor the data returned in the paging data has been already updated?? the paging data operation can take X amount of time how can i wait for the transition in its data after i updated the query term, which triggers the update of the paging data?

```
    @Test
    @VisibleForTesting
    fun onTestForSearch() = runTest {

        // Mock values used in database
        val mockData = CallsMock()
        
        // uut: unit under test
        var uut : List<BaseListItem> = viewModel.allListItemsLiveData.asSnapshot()
        var expectedList = mockData.allData

        // initially uut will return all items since viewmodel starts with
        // query as empty
        assertEquals(expectedList.size, uut.size)

        // update query term, so viewmodel filters data to 
        // only items that contain query term 
        
        viewModel.query.update { mockData.searchTerm }
        uut = viewModel.allListItemsLiveData.asSnapshot()
        expectedList = mockData.searchData
        
        // uut should contain exact same number of items as mock data
        assertEquals(expectedList.size, uut.size) // <-- Fails, uut still has all items, 
                                                  // since paging data requires more time
                                               
        
    }
```